# ElastickSearch Script

Tags: база-данных, elasticsearch, nosql

у меня есть проблема с бд elasticSearch, в документации не найду необходимой информации. У меня есть два индекса, условно, table1 и table2, мне необходимо проверить совпадают ли записи в поле table1 с записями в двух полях в table2, и в том случае если их нет в table1 ДОПИСАТЬ их в поле. Кто нибудь знает как это можно сделать, заранее спасибо.